# after having been an economic afterthought for decades

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is an excerpt from [an APNews article.](https://apnews.com/article/coronavirus-pandemic-business-health-prices-inflation-bd71ae9e491907a51956c1d4eb07fb90)

> The Federal Reserve didn’t anticipate an inflation wave this severe or
> this persistent. In December 2020, the Fed’s policymakers had forecast
> that consumer inflation would stay below their 2% annual target and
> end 2021 at around 1.8%.
>
> But **after having been an economic afterthought for decades**, high
> inflation reasserted itself last year with brutal speed. In February
> 2021, the government’s consumer price index was running just 1.7%
> ahead of its level a year earlier. From there, the year-over-year
> price increases accelerated steadily — 2.7% in March, 4.2% in April,
> 4.9% in May, 5.3% in June.

I wonder which of the following is the meaning of the part in bold.

1. after having been long forgotten,
2. as we always realized it later,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is closer to the first meaning. However, an afterthought isn't really something that is "forgotten"; it is something that is given relatively little attention. (Economists paid more attention to other issues and paid less attention to high inflation.)

Comment: Thank you very much.